# Make two elements inside <ul> tags responsive on the same line

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I would like to know how to make 2 div's inside a  tags responsive, but at the same time the elements have to stay on the same line. Right now the right div is going below the first one. Here is my JSfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/vladicorp/vzSsp/3/

**The code:**

```
<div id="design01">
<div id="titledesign01">Title</div>
                <ul>
                <li>
                <div id="designphoto01"><img src="http://www.emocool.com/work/01.jpg" ></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                <div id="designphoto04"><img src="http://www.emocool.com/work/03.jpg" ></div>
                </li>                
                </ul></div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
   #design01 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float:left;   
}
#design01 ul {
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0px;
    padding:0px;    
}
#design01 ul li{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    padding:0px;
}
#titledesign01 { 
    max-width: 100%;
    font: 18px/20px "HelvBold", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:#fff;
    margin-left:20px;       
}
#designphoto04 {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;

}
#designphoto04 img{

    max-width: 100%    

}

#designphoto01 {

    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;

}

#designphoto01 img{

    max-width: 100%



}
```

Comment: What does "responsive but on the same line" mean? I don't understand what you want to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close.  You just need to add this CSS to your li's to make it work:

```
width:50%;
margin:0;
```

These values can be adjusted.  Basically, we are telling the CSS to let the elements be 50% of the ul width.  If you set it to more than this, they will wrap.  Alternately, you can set one to 40% and the other to 60%, the two values just have to add to 100% (or less if you add padding, margin, or a border).

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8r6dd/)**

Comment: what about if the li elements are different size , for example first one is width:134px and hte second one width: 93px?

Comment: @JohnSiniger Convert them to percents.  93/(93+134)=41%   134/(93+134)=59%  Responsive design requires percents.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of using `float` and `position` try using `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`.